# Can Mac OS lion and Win 7 (Vmware Fusion) Access Fat32 Partition?

Tags: macos, windows, partition, vmware, fat32

Is it possible that I can make partitions on Mac other than the one holding OSX as FAT32. I want to access it via Mac and also when I run Win7 on Vmware Fusion. I can then add that FAT32 partition as Shared Network folder and access its data.

The following is the partition structure I would like to use:

- MacOS = 100GB
- VmWare Fusion Win7 = 120GB
- myStuff Partition = 280GB (which is Fat32 or exFat)

I want to access myStuff partition via OSX as well as VMWare Fusion.

Comment: I am assuming your using VMWare with BootCamp. VMWare allows you to share folders with your guest machine natively and there is no need to format the drives for this?

Comment: No not with BootCamp, VmWare Running directly on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible? **Yes**

Based on your comment, why?

VMWare Fusion runs Windows 7 virtually. Therefore you don't need a partition for it, the OS will simply be installed in a Virtual File on your current HDD, which will grow based on how much space it is using up to the maximum set when you created the virtual machine. Fusion only allows you to use a partition if your using Bootcamp to run Windows already.

Furthermore, Fusion allows you to share folders on your OSX drive with the Virtual Machine directly, without needing to format a partition beforehand, and can also write to your OSX drive natively.

Remember, you are basically running both operating systems at the same time, and Fusion, like Parallels, completely integrates and shares between the 2 operating sysems seamlessly.

What you are referring to in your question is dual booting using Bootcamp, where you can only access one operating system at a time, and no sharing is done.